# How do you get the Frequently Asked Questions to show up in the sidebar?

Tags: feature-request, support, sidebar

I'd like to find a way that a site can have some selected and appropriately tagged canonical-type questions show up in the sidebar of the [site's home page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (not the site's Meta).  It should look kind of like what I see here when I click on "Meta" on the left:

> [image: screenshot of sidebar]

How can this be done?

(Reason: I participate in a couple of sites that get a lot of questions that are variations of the same things over and over.  If they were to read the basics first, they might ask better questions.  Also, this could help us get fewer quick answers written in response to obvious duplicates.)

Answer (score 1):

I often refer to a self-assembling FAQ which can be for a whole site or something more granular.

In the case of this site that would be https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent which is not identical to your graphic but seems to bring back a similar list of questions.

I suggest that your enhancement request could be to give moderators the option to turn on a self-assembling FAQ for a site in their sidebar.